# Test Complete Unable to load URL from Excel

Tags: excel, testcomplete, vbscript, windows-10, keyword-driven

Working on Test Complete Keyword driven framework, which is now migrated from Win7 to Win10. All the environment URLs configuration and actions are in Excel sheet.
Issue: During execution once the browser launched URL is not opening URL is not coming from the excel file
Debug: While debugging found one error .

> Error: Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.

Below is the code to read from Excel:

```
Function GetXLSRecordset(strFilePath, strSQL)
     On Error Resume next
     Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
     'Create Connection srting
     strConnectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;" & _
               "Data Source=" & strFilePath & ";" & _
               "Extended Properties=Excel 16.0"

  Log.Enabled = True
  Log.Message(strFilePath&"::"&strSQL)
  objConnection.Connectionstring = strConnectionstring
  'Open connection for assgined connection string
  objConnection.Open
  'Create new recordset
  Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  'Execute SQL Query
  objRecordset.Open strSQL, objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
  record_Count = objRecordset.RecordCount
  Log.Message("Record Count: "&record_Count)

  Log.Enabled = True
  Set GetXLSRecordset = objRecordset
  objRecordset.Close
  Set objRecordset = Nothing
  objConnection.Close
  Set objConnection = Nothing
End Function
```

---

```
System Configuration:
    TestComplete 14.x 32bit
    MS Excel 16.x 32bit
    MS Access DB driver 16.x 32 bit
    OS Win 10
```

Every time I'll try to print `objRecordset` getting undefined, but it returns the count `objRecordset.RecordCount`

Tried all the possible solution found on community support but didn't work, please suggest me some workaround.

Everything is working properly on win7 machine.